# Is it possible to run a timer task when the application is closed?

Tags: runtime, sharedpreferences, ads, timertask

I have just completed learning Java, now I am working on creating Android apps. But I am not so expert in this field. I have just created an Android app which has some advertisements like banner ad, interstitial ad. I want to give an opportunity to the user to stop those Ads for 24 hours if they watch a video AD. But I'm not familiar with timer task any suggestion will be very appreciating. here is the code that I imagine :

```
// load from shared preference

SharedPreference spref = getSharedPreference("directory_name", 0);
if(spref.getBoolean("ad_key", false)==true){
    // all ads should stop showing
}else{
    // ads are showing
}


// help me here in timer task

As ad reward
--> start countadown
--> if(countDown>0){
    doneWatchindAd(true);
}else{
    doneWatchindAd(false);
}

// store to shared preference

public void doneWatchindAd(bollean cond){
    SharedPreference spref = getSharedPreference("directory_name", 0);
    SharedPreference.Editor editor = spref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("ad_key", cond);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Could you save the time the video ad ended and just periodically check if that was more than 24 hrs ago?

Comment: great idea! thank @Lincoln for your comment, I'll try to do that.